# Compute postgresql query using Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

So basically i need to run the two following queries using Spark SQL but i can not figure out how to to id without my compiler throwing some random errors.

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name, count(p.pid)FROM clubs c
JOIN teams t on c.cid = t.cid
JOIN tournaments d on t.tid = t.tid
JOIN players p on p.ncid = c.ncid
WHERE c.cid = 45 AND d.tyear = 2014
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.tyear, c.name, (SELECT max(m.matchdate) -      min(m.matchdate) FROM matches m WHERE t.tyear = date_part('year', m.matchdate)) AS days  FROM tournaments t
JOIN hosts h ON t.tyear = h.tyear
JOIN countries c on c.cid = h.cid
JOIN stadiums s on s.cid = c.cid
JOIN matches m on m.sid = s.sid
GROUP BY t.tyear, c.name, s.sid
ORDER BY days DESC
```

ive already tried to run query 1 like this but it didnt work:

```
spark1 = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark').getOrCreate()
teams = spark1.read.csv("teams.csv", header = True, mode="DROPMALFORMED").cache()
clubs = spark1.read.csv("clubs.csv", header=True, mode="DROPMALFORMED").cache()
tournaments = spark1.read.csv("tournaments.csv", header = True, mode="DROPMALFORMED")
players = spark1.read.csv("players.csv", header = True, mode="DROPMALFORMED")

spark1.sql('SELECT DISTINCT c.name, count(p.pid)FROM clubs JOIN teams t on c.cid = t.cid JOIN tournaments d on t.tid = t.tid JOIN players p on p.ncid = c.ncid WHERE c.cid = 45 AND d.tyear = 2014 GROUP BY c.name ORDER BY count DESC').show()
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you check your first query it seems like you are using incorrect condition in join of table tournament.

Comment: A stacktrace would be helpful. I doubt the errors are 'random', keep scrolling down the stacktrace to find your issue, or link it here so we can diagnose. There are many things that could be wrong, beyond just the SQL syntax itself.

Comment: this is the error i am getting:  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o90.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)